# Desktop error and getting installed wine version- not

Tags: wine, winetricks

I wanted to check which version of wine I'm updated to, but when I run

```
wine --version
```

in a terminal, it launches 2 wine windows instead of showing me the version. One is titled "**Default - Wine desktop**" with a Program Error box saying

> The program (unidentified) has encountered a serious problem and needs to close

and the other window titled "**1024x768 - Wine desktop**" and no error box in the desktop. Both show the 2 apps on the desktop that I have installed.

Ubuntu 20.04 with gnome. I think I have wine 6, or at least 5. I also have q4wine and winetricks installed.

So

1. How can I resolve the error?
2. How can I verify which version I'm running?

(Couldn't add any tag except 'wine')

Answer (score 0):

OK, got back to looking at this. I tried `aptitude search wine` and got everything wine related, including wine1.4 through wine1.7 all listed as "virtual," which in reading about virtual packages I take it these are supplied by one of the installed wine packages. If I run `aptitude search wine|grep ^i` I get:

```
i  q4wine - Qt GUI for WINE
i  wine-binfmt - Register Wine as the interpreter for Windows executables
i A wine-devel - WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
i A wine-devel-amd64 - WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
i A wine-devel-i386:i386 - WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
i  winehq-devel - WINE Is Not An Emulator - runs MS Windows programs
i  winetricks - simple tool to work around common problems in Wine
```

This is all a bit confusing. I guess the latest "version" I have is effectively wine1.7. Is this last one sometimes referred to as "wine 7?" I will keep digging to try to understand how wine works, and to get a better handle on using winetricks.

I still don't know the answer to why running `wine --help` opens 2 desktops, one with an error, and doesn't show me a version.